# csv read function is not giving approriate output

Tags: database, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
with open('csv_files.csv', 'r') as useFile:
    useFileReader = csv.reader(useFile)
    print("What is in.", useFileReader)

    for row in useFileReader:
        print("im in")   # not getting any output from for loop. 
        print(row)
```

output:
('What is in.', <_csv.reader object at 0x7efbf7eef910>)
[Finished in 0.1s]

Comment: Define "appropriate".

Comment: Maybe your file is empty

Comment: Well the first `print()` is clearly working as expected. However, I would update the line before it to `useFileReader = csv.reader(useFile, delimiter=',')`; replace the `','` with whatever delimiter is in your csv.

Comment: Still the the same out put

Comment: @Aiven, you are right that file was empty, thank you.